# Vuejs use function in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Does anyone know if it's possible to use a function in a v-for loop?
I would like to do something like:

```
<div v-for="(stbc, index) in data">
    <select>
        <option v-for="foo in bar(stbc.arg1, stbc.arg2)" :value="foo">
            {{ foo }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>

[...]
props: {
    Configuration: { required: true }
},
computed: {
    data(){
      return this.Configuration.something
             .filter(stbc => {
               return stbc.val !== "no"
             });
    }
},
methods: {
    bar(arg1, arg2){
        this.$http.get(`server_url/baz?arg1=${arg1}&arg2=${arg2}`)
                  .then(res => { return res.split('\n') });
    }
}
```

I tried but without success :(

Thank you !

Comment: it works.https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/bvqJRB

Comment: i would suggest using filters https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html its probably what you would like to accomplish. but having a call to the server in a loop would slow your page down big time think of  a different way to approach

Comment: Use a computed property

Comment: I guess it doesn't work because you are returning a promise from an AJAX call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v-for` can iterate over a the result of any valid expression (though personally I would consider adding a `computed` property instead).

However, if you're calling the server as you indicate in your comment, you are introducing asynchronous code, and `bar(arg1, arg2)` is probably returning a promise, rather than an array of strings.

I guess what you want to do is:

```
props: {
  Configuration: { required: true }
},
data() {
  return {
    serverData: []
  };
},
mounted() {
  this.fetchData();
},
methods: {
  fetchData() {
    // obtain `arg1` and `arg2` from `this.Configuration`
    // (or use a computed property if you prefer)

    if (arg1 && arg2) {
      this.$http.get(`server_url/baz?arg1=${arg1}&arg2=${arg2}`)
                .then(res => { this.serverData = res.split('\n') });
    }
  }
}
```

Then just refer to `serverData` in your template. The array will be empty until the promise returned by the AJAX call resolves.

If the `Configuration` prop changes during the lifetime of the component, you may want to also add a watcher, to call `fetchData` again with the new values.

Comment: I'm not returning a promise. I'm doing a .then(res => { return res.body.split('\n') }) inside my function

Comment: @MorganLeFloc'h in the code in your question, you are returning nothing from the method. I have updated my example to match what you have added to your question (although I'm not sure where `arg1` and `arg2` come from, so they will need including).

Comment: I'm an idiot x). I've eddited my question so that you know where my args comes from. Your solution is good but I don't know the args value in advance therefore I cannot really apply your solution

Comment: if it comes from the prop `Configuration` then you can compute it before calling the server. I updated again.

Comment: Thanks for your help Tom, but in the end I remade my code as a workaround cause I couldnt figure out how to do it. I would have loved if I could do it the way I've planned, meaning return promise in v-for 
would automatically update when it get the value.

Answer (score 3):

yes, you could use the `computed` to achieve that instead of `methods`, see bellow

```
<select>
    <option v-for="foo in bar(arg1, arg2)" :value="foo">
        {{ foo }}
    </option>
</select>

[...]

computed: {
    bar(arg1, arg2){
        //get data from server
        return serverData; //this is a string array
    }
}
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/2449/

I hope this will help you.

Comment: A computed property that calls the server?

Comment: It won't work for my case. I have two parameters for my function that I need to pass.

Comment: Your "getter"? Do you mean your AJAX call? it will return a promise.

Comment: I tried to clarify what my bar function does by editing my question. Hope it makes it clearer