# How to update a variable from an asynchronous function?

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs3

In my template, **in a `v-slot`** (which means `users` is not available in `<script setup>`), I have

```
<template v-slot:body-cell-assignedTo="props">
  <q-td :props="props">
    <div v-for="u in props.users" :key="u">{{u}}</div>
  </q-td>
</template>
```

This displays

```
john
mary
```

I can enrich this information by calling an API:

```
fetch('https://example.com/api/user/john')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(r => console.log(r))
```

This displays in the console `John de Brown, 1262-1423`.

**My question: how to combine these two mechanisms? In other words, how to asynchronously update the value in `{{}}`?**

I would need to do something like

```
<div v-for="u in props.users" :key="u">{{enrichFetchFunction(u)}}</div>
```

but it would need to be asynchronous, and yet somehow return a value.

**EDIT**: I will ultimately enrich the source data that is displayed in the `v-slot`. I would still be interested, though, if waiting for such an asynchronous function there (à la `await`) is doable in Vuie.

Comment: re-assigning `users` will do the work. Keep in mind how the [reactivity system](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html) works

Comment: Show us the rest of the code

Comment: @wittgenstein: sorry, I was not clear with my question - I updated it to highlight the fact that I cannot update `users` from within `<script setup>`.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how Vue works. Please show us more code.

Comment: @tauzN: I certainly misunderstand something, I am not a professional developer (but developed 20 or so apps in Vue for a few years). I can dump the code of the component, hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Compositions API. See [this playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
const users = ref([])
onMounted(async() => {
  fetch('https://mocki.io/v1/67abcfb6-4f25-4513-b0f9-1eb6c4906413')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(r => users.value = r)
})
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="u in users" :key="u">{{u}}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks - sorry, I was not clear with my question - I updated it to highlight the fact that I cannot update `users` from within `<script setup>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable with [Lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html) such as `mounted()`, yet you will need some sort of listener to react to the information being changed. here is an example that updates the values as soon as it is mounted and includes a button that will also update the values (you can run the code here in [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)):

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1 v-for="u in enrichedUsers" :key="u">{{ u }}</h1>
    <button @click="myAsyncFunction">
      update
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<script>
// pseudo api
const fetchEnrichedAPI = function(user) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    var enrichedUsers = []
    if (user.includes('john')) {
      enrichedUsers.push('John de Brown, 1262-1423')
    }
    if (user.includes('mary')){
      enrichedUsers.push('Mary de Purple, 1423-1262')
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(enrichedUsers);
    }, 300);
  });
}

export default{
  data() {
    return {
      props : { users: ['john','mary'] },
      enrichedUsers: []
    }
  },
  
  mounted() {
    // when mounted run this async function
    this.myAsyncFunction()
  },

  methods: {
    async myAsyncFunction() {
      // call api passing the list of users
      await fetchEnrichedAPI(this.props.users)
        .then((data) => {
          // if api work
          this.enrichedUsers = data;
          return true;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          // if the api doesn't work
          console.error(e);
          this.enrichedUsers = this.props.users;
        })
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

I am aware that this does not use props, but it does work. If you would like to expand this to use props you may be able to do this with computed properties or functions in the v-for. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49407356/12846242) for more info on that.